# In Django-admin, how to show details for manytomany relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

In django-admin, It's not convenient to edit a `manytomany` field in a new page，besides this, I wanna show more details in `edit_inline` area as `foreignkey` field does. What should I do to achieve this needs

This is foreignkey field:
[image]

and this is manytomany field:

[image]

can I edit manytomany field in this page? At least show some column in this area.

Answer (score 2):

For the manytomany try using
(in admin.py)

```
filter_horizontal = ('fieldname', )
```

about the foreignkey, create a form for that inline and do something like...

```
forms.CharField(label='',required=False,
                widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'style': 'height: 20em;'}))
```